# SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

[image]

Hi, I have a problem. I can't save the sketch. When I Save, an error will come out in the console Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 56. In this error console there is also a mention about the _uploadFile function. Is there anyone who can help me why this error occurs.

[image]

Code:

```
  _uploadAndSave() async {
        setState(() {
          _progressBarActive = true;
        });
    
        _bytesData = await _controller.toPngBytes();
        _bytesDataBodyDiagram = await _bodySketchcontroller.toPngBytes();
        _bytesDataRightHeadDiagram = await _rightHeadSketchcontroller.toPngBytes();
        _bytesDataLeftHeadDiagram = await _leftHeadSketchcontroller.toPngBytes();
    
        var sketch = '';
        var bodyDiagramSketch = '';
        var rightHeadDiagramSketch = '';
        var leftHeadDiagramSketch = '';
    
        if (_bytesData != null) {
          sketch = await _uploadFile(_bytesData!);
        }
    
        if (_bytesDataBodyDiagram != null) {
          bodyDiagramSketch = await _uploadFile(_bytesDataBodyDiagram!);
        }
    
        if (_bytesDataRightHeadDiagram != null) {
          rightHeadDiagramSketch = await _uploadFile(_bytesDataRightHeadDiagram!);
        }
    
        if (_bytesDataLeftHeadDiagram != null) {
          leftHeadDiagramSketch = await _uploadFile(_bytesDataLeftHeadDiagram!);
        }
    
        _savePatientEvaluation(sketch, bodyDiagramSketch, rightHeadDiagramSketch,
            leftHeadDiagramSketch);
      }


Future<String> _uploadFile(Uint8List? fileBytes) async {
    /*if(symptoms.text.length < 1){
      _alertDialog(context, 'Symptom details is required.');
      return;
    }

    if(consultationNotes.text.length < 3){
      _alertDialog(context, 'Consultation notes is required.');
      return;
    }*/

    /*if(_bytesData == null){
      if(complaintDescription.text.length < 1){
        _alertDialog(context, 'Complaint description is required.');
        return;
      }
    }*/

    if (fileBytes == null) {
      if (complaintDescription.text.length < 1) {
        _alertDialog(context, 'Complaint description is required.');
        setState(() {
          _progressBarActive = false;
        });
        return 'error';
      }
    }

    if (treatmentPlan.text.length < 3) {
      _alertDialog(context, 'Treatment plan is required.');
      setState(() {
        _progressBarActive = false;
      });
      return 'error';
    }

    setState(() {
      _progressBarActive = true;
    });

    //_selectedFile = _bytesData;
    _selectedFile = fileBytes!;

    print("Upload start...");
    if (_selectedFile.length < 1) {
      _alertDialog(context, 'Please select a photo.');
      return 'error';
    }

    var fileName = dateEpocMilisecond.toString() + "_616w_512h_3s_diag.png";
    var uri = Uri.parse(widget.apiEndPoint);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    request.fields['MultipartFile'] = 'true';
    request.fields['API'] = 'UploadImage';
    request.fields['Token'] = widget.token;

    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('File', _selectedFile,
        contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'), filename: fileName));

    var streamedResponse = await request.send();
    var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

    setState(() {
      _progressBarActive = false;
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
      if (result['ResponseCode'] == "0") {
        if (result['Data'] != null) {
          print(result['Data']['banner']);
          //_savePatientEvaluation(result['Data']['banner']);
          return result['Data']['banner'].toString();
        }
      } else if (result['ResponseCode'] != "0") {
        if (result['ResponseCode'] == "1") {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/signin', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        } else {
          _alertDialog(context, result['ResponseMsg']);
          return 'error';
        }
      }
    } else {
      return 'error';
    }

    return 'error';
  }
```

Comment: That means json.decode() got a String but not in json format. You need to check what `response.body` really is. Try to print `response.body` out, check if its a json.